# Adapt animation PathGeometry based on window scaling

Tags: wpf, animation

I am trying to animate an object along a path. I am using two DoubleAnimationUsingPath to animate its X and Y coordinates, and it works fine. What I would like to do is scale the animation so that when the window size changes the animation changes it proportions as well, adapting to that of the window.

I have tried applying a ScaleTransform to the PathGeometry of the animations, with the transform's ScaleX and ScaleY properties bound to a property I added to the window which keeps track of the change in scale after a resize, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Simply put, I would like my animation to scale according to the size of the Window. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[ViewBox](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html) control should make the trick in simple scenarios.